When `stripe_dashboard[type]=none` and `requirement_collection=stripe`, Stripe must be liable for negative balances or refunds and chargebacks
I'm currently starting to use the Stripe.net library and I'm creating an online market place for sellers and buyers.
I have this in my Ui where the UI takes in some information from the user:

And I'm using this in .NET to onboard the user:
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "xxxx";
var options = new AccountCreateOptions
{
Country = data.country,
Email = data.businessEmail,
Capabilities = new AccountCapabilitiesOptions()
{
    CardPayments = new AccountCapabilitiesCardPaymentsOptions(){ Requested = true },
    Transfers = new AccountCapabilitiesTransfersOptions { Requested = true },
},
Controller = new AccountControllerOptions
{
    Fees = new AccountControllerFeesOptions { Payer = "application" },
    Losses = new AccountControllerLossesOptions { Payments = "application" },
    StripeDashboard = new AccountControllerStripeDashboardOptions
    {
        Type = "none",
    },
    RequirementCollection = "stripe"
},
};
var service = new AccountService();
service.Create(options);

But I keep getting this error:
'When `stripe_dashboard[type]=none` and `requirement_collection=stripe`, Stripe must be liable for negative balances or refunds and chargebacks.'

I am setting the requirement_collection=stripe, so where am I going wrong?
I have a connected account which I setup as standard.

The error message is saying that Stripe has to be the party liable for losses. Your code explicitly passed Losses = new AccountControllerLossesOptions { Payments = "application" }, which means you're making yourself (your application) liable for those losses. This combination of options is not supported at the moment.
Switch to stripe for that loss liability and it should work as expected.
